# Change configuration in runtime by changing environment variables using the module node-config

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to use the node-config module to change some parameters of my configuration (basically logging level) during runtime. 
In the official documentation says:

> Environment variables can be used to override file configurations. Any environment variable that starts with $CONFIG_ is set into the CONFIG object.

I've checked that this is true when the server starts but it does not seem to work once it's up. (The handler of the watch function is never called when an environment variable is changed unlike a change in the runtime.json file or directly changing a config variable).

I'm currently watching the whole CONFIG object like this:

```
var CONFIG = require('config');
CONFIG.watch( CONFIG , null , function(object, propertyName, priorValue, newValue){
    console.log("Configuration change detected");
});
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The environment is available during startup of a process.
If the process is running, you won't be able to change the environment anymore, the process is in.

The only option is to restart the process or use other mechanisms to communicate with it.
Say for example having a rest or tcp listener inside, where you can transfer your variable inside.

Best regards
   Robert

Answer (score 0):

As you must knowing, React is a single page application which is eventually when it is complied  is a static page app that means all the files of the react application is complied into vanilla JS and CSS file bundle in a Tarball. Now that Tarball is eventually deployed on a web server. It could be  Apache web server, nginx web server or anything which you are using it but an important point is  the static app is running in someone else browser and someone access to website CSS and JS are downloaded in a browser and it is running in the browser runtime environment so technically you cannot have a runtime environment variable for someone else browser but may be there would be a way to access them during runtime.

**SOLUTION**
I have achieved this goal with the package called **runtime-cra**.

follow the steps on this official documentation: **https://blog.risingstack.com/create-react-app-runtime-env-cra/**